# Reduce MaterialCalanderView Background Image Size

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am using material calander view in my application. For some dates I highlight background. The problem is that if two consecutive dates have background then they overlap each other. So I want t o reduce the size of background. Below is the code I am using 
For drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid
    android:color="@color/dark_blue"/>

<size
    android:width="15dp"
    android:height="15dp"/>
```

And in Java when I am setting decorator

```
 public class CurrentDateDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return day.equals(CalendarDay.today());
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.day_transparent_border));
        view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK));
    }
}
```

How can I reduce background. I tried reducing size in shape drawable but its not working

See attached image[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: will you pls. upload screenshot here ?

Comment: Added Screenshot

Comment: I want at least 2dp gap between backgrounds

Comment: checkout is there any app:mcv_tileSize="40dp" property applicable ?

Comment: That is reducing the calendar size, not the background of particular dates

Comment: try it with 300dp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147352/discussion-between-unflagged-destination-and-zaptechdev-kumar).

Comment: Tried with 300 as well. Its showing empty screen then